# How to create more than one document root in apache2

Tags: apache2, document, root

I would like to create a virtual host in apache2, but I want it to place the source files outside the /var/www folder, i.e. I need to include another document root in the config files, but I implemented it by editing the apache/sites-available/default file, but I know its not the right way to implement, can any one suggest the correct way of implementing it?

with thank and regards,

bala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new file (e.g. `myvirtualhost`) in the `sites-available` folder and then create a symlink in the `sites-enabled`. The file and the symlink can have any name.

Inside the new file you create a new virtual host definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/webapplication
    ServerName abc.local
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are deploying your application only locally for testing it is enough to set the server name to a .local domain (e.g `abc.local`) in this case you should edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add a new line like.

```
127.0.0.1 abc.local
```

If you want to make the new virtual host available on the internet you need to make sure that you have registered a valid DNS name with your provider (e.g. `webapplication.mydomain.com`).

Basically thats it. You may however want to add some  directives to the virtual host definition to control access to your resources.

Comment: omgod why other answers did't mention the hosts file is a mystery

Answer (score 1):

you can go to your httpd.conf file (apache config file located in conf directory). Then find a line which reads:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

then uncomment the second line like this:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

go to your "extra" folder also located in the conf foler. You will see file named "httpd-vhosts.conf"

Edit the file in the virtual host samples:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "...full path to you new root folder for this site...."
    ServerName yourwebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.yourwebsite.com
    ErrorLog "logs/newpath.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/newpath.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

but this is very simplified solution, please read more on virtual hosts, but it should point you to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to the already existing answers. You don't strictly need to edit the hosts file on your system. You can just use another local ip , ie instead of using 127.0.0.1 you can use 127.0.0.2. in fact it can be any ip that starts with 127

Your virtual hsot definition will then be like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/webapplication
    ServerName 127.0.0.2
</VirtualHost>
```